# Adding element (circle) on background but behind a text in html css js

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to add couple of (bigger) circles on a background image (html, css), but they need to be behind a text. What is the best way to do this?
It should look something like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBU5u.png)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest is to create an image with circles. Then set that image as a background of the element that is holding your text. For example:

```
<div class="yourHolder">
YOUR TEXT
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.yourHolder {
background: src(images/yourimage.jpg);
}
```